# How to print all the acronyms?

Tags: glossaries, acronyms

In my figures I used some acronyms (i.e. embedded in the figures, not readable by LaTeX). I included all the acronyms in a file. LaTeX only printed the acronyms appeared in the text, and ignored other acronyms I included. How to make LaTeX print all the acronyms? Thanks!

Update: In addition, I don't want the pages where the acronyms appear to be shown. Because LaTeX could not read the acronyms in the figures, for those figure-embedded acronyms, there would be no page displayed next to them. It would appear inconsistent: some acronyms with pages next to them and some without. Therefore, I don't want the pages where the acronyms appear to be shown.

Comment: Use `\glsaddall`

Comment: Use `nonumberlist` option to prevent the page list from showing or use `\glsadd{label}` next to `\includegraphics` for each acronym shown in the figure to include the page.

Comment: Thanks, both! I used `\glsaddallunused`and `\printglossary[type=\acronymtype, nonumberlist]`. Update: At first I used `\glsaddall`, but it didn' work. I don't know why. But now it seems both `\glsaddall` and `\glsaddallunused` could work.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question was solved in the comments.

Comment: How to close it? Should I delete my question?

Comment: @NicolaTalbot Seems your comment comment solved the problem. Would you like to write an answer?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Same comment for you, but I thought "lady's first"

Comment: @samcarter: That's fine. I think Nicola should answer, she's the package guru ;-)

Comment: @samcarter and Christian You're both very courteous :-)

Comment: @TeXnician I don't think questions should be closed for that reason. The site bots automatically remove comments from time to time as part of site maintenance. It could be closed as a dup, since this question has come up before, but it has an extra angle to usual as the underlying problem stems from acronyms in image files.

Comment: @NicolaTalbot: You're the `glossaries` guru ... ;-)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are various methods. First is to use `nonumberlist` (either as a package option or in `\printglossary`) in combination with `\glsaddall` (which must be used after all acronyms have been defined).

For example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage[acronym,nonumberlist]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newacronym{ac1}{ac1}{acronym 1}
\newacronym{ac2}{ac2}{acronym 1}

\glsaddall

\begin{document}
\gls{ac1}.

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics{example-image}
\caption{A Figure}
\end{figure}

\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

This omits all page numbers and includes all entries.

The second method doesn't use `nonumberlist` or `\glsaddall` but instead uses `\glsaddallunused`. This command must go at the end of the document:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newacronym{ac1}{ac1}{acronym 1}
\newacronym{ac2}{ac2}{acronym 1}

\begin{document}
\gls{ac1}.

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics{example-image}
\caption{A Figure}
\end{figure}

\printglossaries

\glsaddallunused

\end{document}
```

This displays the page list for `ac1` which has been used in the document, but not for `ac2`.

For the third method, let's suppose `ac2` is displayed in the image. Instead of using `\glsaddallused`, you can index `ac2` next to the image. Like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newacronym{ac1}{ac1}{acronym 1}
\newacronym{ac2}{ac2}{acronym 1}

\begin{document}
\gls{ac1}.

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics{example-image}\glsadd{ac2}
\caption{A Figure}
\end{figure}

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

This doesn't display any text next to the image, but it does index `ac2`, which means that `ac2` now appears in the acronym list with the page number on which the image appears.

Comment: This is not working on my side. How do you compile it?

Comment: Well it does work with pdflatex > makeglossaries > pdflatex. Thanks

Comment: For me it was: `pdflatex > makeglossaries > pdflatex > pdflatex`

Comment: @Nicola Talbot using \glsaddallunused imports GCDGreatest Common Divisor. into my list of acronyms even though I haven't defined it.
This must be some kind of bug as GCD is a basic example.. Any idea how to get rid of this? Have you experienced this also?